# Using a Format file with a hex row terminator

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I am attempting to use BULK INSERT with a format file to import a text file.  I need to use a format file to address some formatting issues with the import file.

When I attempt to import the file I get the following error message 'Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1' for the last column in each row.

In troubleshooting this error I attempted to import the file without the format file, which works (aside from the formatting I was going to take care in the format file).

Below is the Code that works:

```
    BULK INSERT #TEMP_TABLE
    FROM $IMPORT/PATH/FILENAME.txt
    WITH (
      FIRSTROW = 2
    , DATAFILETYPE = 'char'
    , FIELDTERMINATOR = ','
    , ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
    )
```

Please note that if I change the row terminator to '\n' the above stops working. I get an error message: 'Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 1'

As you might guess the issue I am running into is that I cannot use the hex code '0x0a' in my format file but '/n' does not work.  I have been troubleshooting this issue for over a full workday and I am still no closer to an answer.  If you can offer any assistance I will be quite thankful.